# Can Not locate "Input" terminal on node "xxx"

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I have such error. I tried clean project , rebuild but not works[image]

Error Message: 
**Can not locate "Input_1" terminal on node "getProcessOTP (Implementation)"    otprestservices.msgflow /otprestservices/gen    Unknown Message Flow Connection Problem**

Comment: I recraed and problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem there was a bug. I recreated and problem is solved